# 'Mongo::OperationFailure' for some actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo. I've installed Mongodb from [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) source. I'm using the mongodb for Rails application. The app loads fine after starting the mongodb and rails. However, it fails when I try to login. The same thing happens when I try to perform some operations in rails console.

Here the model code:

```
  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find(:first, :conditions => {:email => email})
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
     nil
    end
  end
```

Its failing at `if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)`

Here is the short error:

> Database command 'create' failed: {"ok"=>0.0, "errmsg"=>"collection already exists", "code"=>48}

And, the full application error trace:

> mongo (1.3.1) lib/mongo/db.rb:506:in `command'
>   mongo (1.3.1) lib/mongo/db.rb:284:in`create_collection'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/collections/master.rb:41:in `initialize'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/collection.rb:127:in`new'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/collection.rb:127:in `master'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/collection.rb:60:in`find_one'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/contexts/mongo.rb:164:in `first'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:42:in`one'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/criterion/inclusion.rb:104:in `find'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid/finders.rb:83:in`find'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:435:in `_run__902337259577170033__process_action__4476240526817474042__callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in`instrument'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in `process'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in`process'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in`call'
>   rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
>   rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in`block in recognize'
>   rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
>   rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in`recognize'
>   rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in`call'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/mongoid.rb:130:in`unit_of_work'
>   mongoid (2.2.1) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in`_run_call_callbacks'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in`call'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'
>   activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`block in call'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in`call'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
>   railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in`call'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
>   rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in`service'
>   /Users/reonios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>   /Users/reonios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   /Users/reonios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show model and code?

Comment: @HarryBomrah I've added the model code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the code and googling I found that a special character was sent in every request. My request parameters were like this:

```
{  
   "utf8"=>"âœ“",
   "authenticity_token"=>"cAcdDOzfBgalF5em+97mTKw9DAjymfmEmG6hc+dDqhQ=",
   "email"=>"super_admin_user@test.com",
   "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
   "commit"=>"Login"
}
```

Not sure what triggered 'âœ'. But one of the post in google says, there is a bug related to this present in the 2.2 series and that is got fixed with later versions.

So, I found my *mongoid* version to be 2.2.1 and once I had it upgraded the problem got resolved.

NOTE: Am new to *mongoid* and gave a solution with minimal knowledge. Please add details if needed.